# Inserting a char into MySQL varchar value

Tags: mysql, substring, concatenation

Is there a MySQL function to easily insert a character or characters into the value of a varchar column?

I want to set the following text:

`B U 1 U 09 2011 Segs 1, 3 - 10 24 hours`

To

`B U 1 U N 09 2011 Segs 1, 3 - 10 24 hours`

Comment: can you explain why `N` is inserted between `U` and `09`? :D

Comment: It is the preferred naming convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `SELECT` a value with it you can use:

```
select concat(left(col, 8), 'N ', substring(col, 9))
from table1
```

If you want to `UPDATE` you can use:

```
update table1
set col = concat(left(col, 8), 'N ', substring(col, 9))
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12b49/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT INSERT('B U 1 U 09 2011 Segs 1, 3 - 10 24 hours', 8, 0, ' N');
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/3998

More info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_insert